# WordPress Can't Add new Page/Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with my WordPress and I don't know why.

I disabled all plugins, activated the default theme twenty seventeen.

Permalinks are ok I also checked that.
I even changed the edit.php file from a different WordPress where it's working.But no luck.

**The problem is when I try to add new page or post it redirects me to wp-admin/edit.php.**

I also checked **httacces**, nothing there either.
**wp-debug** is turned on, no errors in console nor site.
Can someone help me out?Thank You.

Comment: Did you have some plugin that was manipulating user privileges? Maybe your user account does not have the right to add new posts anymore.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó i disabled all the plugins , and also used the main account for the login

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling WordPress? (wp-admin -> Dashboard -> Updates -> Re-install button)

Comment: @ZoliSzabó I will try to install it now again

Comment: try to overwrite new wp-admin folder ... and then check it

Answer (score 1):

I'll pop my solution in here as these threads seem to reach the top of search results and it was complete accident I resolved the same issue (like you it had nothing to do with .htaccess):

If using PHP 5.6, change from FPM to FastCGI. Curiously, when we upgraded to 7.2, both FastCGI and FPM worked. Be advised that other plugins, themes etc. may have compatability issues as swapping PHP has knock-on effects.

If you're unable to do so, there are some other troubleshooting methods which are worth trying on top of disabling themes/plugins;

- In Settings > Permalinks, change the URL format to "Plain", Save, then change it back to whatever you had before and Save again
- Reinstall Wordpress by going to "Updates" > Re-install now

Answer (score 0):

Just followed these steps:

"In Settings > Permalinks, change the URL format to "Plain", Save, then change it back to whatever you had before and Save again

Reinstall Wordpress by going to "Updates" > Re-install now"

It works for me. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).